# Loop for xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

The source xlsx file has content like this:

```
  First
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
6  f
```

I read the data from the source file (starting with cell A3) with pandas:

```
data = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=2)
dataset_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['First'])
```

In this column are about 40 entries.
Then i write the content to a list:

```
list_col_1 = dataset_1.values.tolist()
```

When I try to write the list to a column in a new xlsx file i got an error message that 'lists' are not allowed:

```
worksheet1.write_row('A4', list_col_1)
```

when i try the following it works for the first entry starting at cell A4 (in the cells above is some content):

```
worksheet1.write_row('A4', list_col_1[0])
```

Now i need a for-loop to do this for every entry in the list or is there an other way to do this?
I don't have any idea how to write the for-loop.

The result should look like:

```
   First
1
2
3
4   a
5   b
6   c
```

Comment: Add the format of output you want to get, please. How the result table in excel must look like.

Why do you need to do this transform "list_col_1 = dataset_1.values.tolist()"?
What is "A4"? Do you want to write to specific worksheet into exel-file?

Comment: i add the format to the question. the pandas docu said i can write to a list with this function. A4 is the start cell where i want to start writing and if you have a solution for a specific worksheet it would be great. thanks a lot